# Como cargo y almaceno ciertas filas y columnas de un archivo csv con la libreria pandas en una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv') #Cargo el archivo csv

#x = df.drop('class', axis=1) #features values
x = df.iloc[0:,1:]
#y = df['class'] #target value
y = df.iloc[0:,:1]

print(x)
print(y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

print(x_train)
print(y_train)

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier

pipelines = {
    'lr':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression()),
    'rc':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RidgeClassifier()),
    'rf':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier()),
    'gb':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier()),
}

fit_models = {}

for algo, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
    fit_models[algo] = model

print(fit_models)

print(fit_models['lr'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['rc'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['rf'].predict(x_test))
print(fit_models['gb'].predict(x_test))
```

Como hago para que los datos encuadrados en rojo del csv que se ven en la siguiente screenshot de Excel(delimitados por el simbolo de la coma), que serian los targets, queden guardados en la variable `y` , y los que estan encuadrados en azul que serian las features (x1,y1,z1,v1,x2,y2,z2,v2,...,x501,y501,z501,v501) que se deben guardar en la variable `x`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo he intentado con la funcion .iloc pero no ha funcionado correctamente con esto:

```py
x = df.iloc[0:,1:]
y = df.iloc[0:,:1]
```

Me sale lo siguiente cuando imprimo `x`, ademas en la siguiente screenshot tambien se ve el error que da la funcion `fit()` de scikit-learn, al intentar entrenar un modelo con esos datos que no se pueden cargar correctamente del csv.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto sale cuando imprimo la variable `y`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ambos casos los datos que carga del archivo csv son incorrectos y no entiendo el porque, ya que se supone que el iloc deberia seleccionar esas filas y columnas.

No se si es util para el problema, pero el codigo con el que cree el csv, es el siguiente (aqui un fragmento):

```
pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark

pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

face = results.face_landmarks.landmark

face_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in face]).flatten())

row = pose_row+face_row
row.insert(0, class_name)

with open('coords.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Al momento de leer el csv dile a pandas que el limitador es `;`

Comment: muchas gracias, no se porque yo habia creado el csv con el delimitador de la coma `,` pero luego edite unas filas en Excel y cuando lo volvi a cargar daba ese error, supongo que el Excel le cambio el delimitador a `;` cuando le di a guardar los cambios. Ahi lo intente con `df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv',sep=';')`

Comment: al momento de crear el csv lo puedes hacer con pandas, no hace falta `csv`. Al tener tu dataframe puedes hacer `df.to_csv("archivo.csv")`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: si pudiste solucionar tu problema?

Comment: estaba teniendo un otro problema ahora aunque no se si tiene que ver, porque cuandoo hice eso que mensionaste me slaio esto `File "C:\Users\Maty0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py", line 243, in _check_optimize_result
    ).format(solver, result.status, result.message.decode("latin1"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: cuando edite eso me empezo a aparecer este error de decode en al misma linea del `    model = pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)`

Comment: El ertorbdice un string no tiene el método `decode`, ese método lo tienen las cadenas de byte. Se soluciona haciendo `result.message.encode().decode("latin1")`

Comment: que es lo que esta dando ese error? los nombres de las str que se hallan en el y_train? o los floats que se hallan en x_train al pasarles al fit()  ?  Ademas como haria para cargar los datos del csv que vienen como str, y luego llevarlos a cadena de bytes con esa funcion decode() que mencionas?

Comment: Creo que deberías hacer una nueva pregunta, pues el error es completamente distinto y todo el contexto cambia

Comment: Ok entiendo, entonces haria otra preg con eso. De todos modos aprovecho para decirte de nuevo gracias por la ayuda